# Why isn't my environment using mdframed working?

Tags: environments, mdframed

I am trying to make a new environment using `mdframed` but some of the options I am trying to define are not working.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twosided]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framemethod]{mdframed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdfdefinestyle{mdfexample1}{leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=2cm,%
innerleftmargin=1cm,innerrightmargin=1cm,roundcorner=10pt}
\newmdenv[skipabove=15pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=true,
leftline=true,
topline=true,
bottomline=true,
linecolor=green,
backgroundcolor=green!10,
innerleftmargin=15pt,
innerrightmargin=15pt,
innertopmargin=15pt,
leftmargin=2cm,
rightmargin=2cm,
linewidth=2pt,
innerbottommargin=15pt,
roundcorner=10pt]{mBox}

\newenvironment{caixa}
{\begin{mBox}\onehalfspacing\small\color{blue}\ttfamily}{\end{mBox}}
\begin{document}
\begin{caixa}
\begin{itemize}
\item Parque 1
\item Parque 2
\end{itemize}
\end{caixa}

\begin{mdframed}[style=mdfexample1]
In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse
is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two
 legs.
 \end{mdframed}
 \end{document}
```

This is the result I am getting:
[image: mdframed]

As you can see, it is not respecting several options I define, such as `roundcorners`, `leftmargin` and `rightmargin`. Does anyone know what is going wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `setspace` is also missing and the color definitions !

Comment: @Moriambar Sorry, I am working in a book, so I had just copied the main package, I should work now!

Comment: @LauraP sure. A side note: `color` is superseded by `xcolor` so it is not necessary to use it

Comment: @Moriambar: David will with furious anger lay his vengeance on you ;-)

Comment: Also `mdframed` already calls `xcolor` so…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `framemethod` must be specified to be `tikz`, not the empty `framemethod` key.

If working in `twoside` mode, the `outermargin` and `innermargin` options should be used instead of `rightmargin` and `leftmargin`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\colorlet{azul}{blue}


\makeatletter % The code checks for twoside or oneside options
\if@twoside
\mdfdefinestyle{mdfexample1}{
  innermargin=1cm,
  outermargin=2cm,%
  innerleftmargin=1cm,
  innerrightmargin=1cm,
  roundcorner=10pt}
\else
\mdfdefinestyle{mdfexample1}{
  leftmargin=1cm,
  rightmargin=2cm,%
  innerleftmargin=1cm,
  innerrightmargin=1cm,
  roundcorner=10pt}
\fi
\makeatother

\newmdenv[skipabove=15pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=true,
leftline=true,
topline=true,
bottomline=true,
linecolor=green,
backgroundcolor=green!10,
innerleftmargin=15pt,
innerrightmargin=15pt,
innertopmargin=15pt,
leftmargin=2cm,
rightmargin=2cm,
linewidth=2pt,
innerbottommargin=15pt,
roundcorner=10pt]{mBox}

\newenvironment{caixa}
{\begin{mBox}\onehalfspacing\small\color{azul}\ttfamily}{\end{mBox}}
\begin{document}
\begin{caixa}
\begin{itemize}
\item Parque 1
\item Parque 2
\end{itemize}
\end{caixa}

\begin{mdframed}[style=mdfexample1]
In any right triangle, the area of the square whose side is the hypotenuse
is equal to the sum of the areas of the squares whose sides are the two
 legs.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hupfer, any idea why it isn't obeying the margins' options?

Comment: @LauraP: See the updated solution. The black frame in the screen shot is from `showframe` package, just ignore it

Comment: @LauraP: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!